# error in disk partitioning during ubuntu server 12 installing

Tags: installation

I'm installing ubuntu server-12 on my computer that has a 2 GHz intel processor, 2 GB RAM and 160 GB Sata hard drive. I'm installing from a CD. Everything goes fine; however when I get to partitioning the hard drive, I get this (I'd post the image, but ask ubuntu doesn't let me yet):

[!!] Partition disks
       ??? ???

Comment: post the image to imgur.com and provide the link here.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure Ubuntu can see your hard-drive('s), are your Hard-drive('s) connected to a raid? if so find out if your raid controller is compatible.

If not try and boot from a live disc and format the hard-drive('s) from within ubuntu.

If that fails try using partition magic (or any other hard-drive checking software) to test your drive as it may just be a dead hard-drive